# Github pages Modelica language syntax highlighting not working

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, modelica, kramdown, rouge

I tried a simple test in Github pages to be able to include Modelica language but the highlight does not work on github pages whereas it is working in github markdown rendering

Working here :
https://github.com/gautierbureau/gautierbureau.github.io/blob/master/index.md

Not working here :
https://gautierbureau.github.io/

I read some stuff abut backtick and tilde and used both but did not change anything... Then I also read some stuff about rouge syntax highlighter but it dit not work either (maybe my configuration was not good but I couln't find any simple solution...)

Comment: Rouge uses different grammars it seems, and there just is no grammar yet for Modelica, e.g. in the dropdown menu here: http://rouge.jneen.net/ but at least there is a corresponding issue: https://github.com/jneen/rouge/issues/989

Comment: help page is here: https://help.github.com/articles/using-syntax-highlighting-on-github-pages/ and list of supported languages is here: https://github.com/jneen/rouge/wiki/List-of-supported-languages-and-lexers

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful